# O que é baseline?

Tags: html, css

Estudando [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background) (tipo de leiaute em HTML/CSS), me deparei com esse conceito de ***baseline***, que nunca tinha visto antes:

> ## align-items
>
> ...
>
> [image: Exemplo do uso de baseline com flexbox]
>
> ...
>
> - `baseline`: itens são alinhados de forma que seus *baselines* se alinhem

Pesquisando por aí, vi que isso não é algo novo do Flexbox, mas já usado em outros contextos, como [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

> **baseline**
> Alinha o *baseline* do elemento com o *baseline* do seu *parent*. O *baseline* de alguns elementos substituídos, como `<textarea>`, não é especificado pela especificação do HTML, o que significa que seu comportamento com essa palavra-chave pode mudar de um *browser* para outro.

Etc. Entretanto, não encontrei à primeira vista nenhuma explicação *do que é* esse *baseline*. Me parece ter algo a ver com tipografia, com a forma com que as letras se dispõem uma em relação às outras. Mas não tenho certeza. Estou interessado em saber especificamente como esse conceito funciona num contexto de HTML/CSS:

- Onde está esse *baseline*, e qual sua relação com outras características do box (`margin`, `padding`, etc) e do texto (`font-size`, `line-height`, etc)?
- É preciso que um elemento tenha *algum* texto para o *baseline* existir/fazer sentido?
- Qual a importância prática dele? Imagino que seja importante, já que ele é o valor padrão para `vertical-align`... Existem situações específicas em que seu uso é desejável/indesejável?

Comment: Tambem fiquei curioso pela questão e achei esse otimo artigo. [http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/17/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/17/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/) Fica de referencia para os interessaados.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O conceito vem mesmo da tipografia. A [*baseline*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)) é a **linha de base** onde o texto se assenta. Se você estiver escrevendo em uma folha pautada, a *baseline* equivale à própria pauta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>[Fonte da imagem](http://euedesign.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/tipografia.html)</sup>

Na figura dá para ver que ela não é o limite inferior da área ocupada pelo texto, já que as [descendentes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) das letras (como a "perna" do "p") ficam abaixo da linha de base.

No CSS, o conceito é importante quando se lida com texto, e com elementos [`inline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting) em geral (incluindo os elementos com `display: inline-block` e `display: inline-table`). Todo o processo de layout determinado pelo CSS é baseado em caixas (*boxes*), e essas caixas podem ser de diversos tipos, o que é determinado pela propriedade `display` do elemento e pelo tipo do conteúdo. Veja este exemplo, [retirado da especificação do CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#display):

```
<p>Somebody whose name I have
forgotten, said, long ago: <q>a box is
a box,</q> and he probably meant it.</p>
```

```
p { display: block }
q { display: block; margin: 1em }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As caixas com fundo cinza da figura são caixas de linha (*line boxes*). Repare que a caixa inclui as "pernas" do "y", do "g" e do "p". Ou seja, a caixa contém a linha toda, com os caracteres completos. No exemplo, cada linha do parágrafo gera uma caixa dessas. Essas caixas são geradas automaticamente pelo browser ao processar o conteúdo que será renderizado, e obedecem aos seguintes princípios:

- Só existe uma caixa de linha por linha de texto
- Não é possível manipular caixas de linha diretamente com CSS, apenas indiretamente: se a linha contém elementos `inline` ou `inline-block`, a caixa de linha envolve esses elementos completamente, portanto sua altura pode variar de acordo com a altura do conteúdo.
- **A linha de base pertence à caixa de linha**.

O exemplo a seguir mostra como o conteúdo da linha pode influir na altura da caixa e na posição da linha de base. A palavra do meio tem um tamanho de fonte cinco vezes maior que o texto em torno dela, e por isso afeta a posição vertical da linha de base da caixa de linha toda (caso contrário, parte do texto ficaria cortado ou desalinhado):

```css
p { border: 1px solid red; }
span { font-size: 5em; }
```

```html
<p>Lorem <span>ipsum</span> dolor</p>
```

O mesmo tipo de consequência existe para outras propriedades com texto, como `line-height` (que é o espaçamento entre múltiplas caixas de linha num mesmo contexto). Margens e *padding* podem ou não influir na posição da linha de base, dependendo da propriedade `display` do elemento. Por exemplo, margens verticais não se aplicam a elementos `inline`, e neles o *padding* se projeta para fora, sem afetar as dimensões do container nem a posição da linha de base:

```css
p { border: 1px solid red; }
span { 
    padding: 2em 0;
    margin: 2em 0; /* não faz nada */
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem <span>ipsum</span> dolor</p>
```

Já nos elementos `inline-block` essas propriedades (e também `height`) afetam a linha:

```css
p { border: 1px solid red; }
span { 
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2em 0;
    margin: 2em 0;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem <span>ipsum</span> dolor</p>
```

Tentando responder às suas perguntas finais:

> É preciso que um elemento tenha algum texto para o baseline existir/fazer sentido?

É preciso haver uma caixa de linha, e as caixas de linha são geradas por qualquer conteúdo inline dentro de um bloco. Mas o conceito não faz sentido se não houver texto. Por exemplo, se dentro de um parágrafo houver duas imagens, elas irão se alinhar por baixo (a linha de base corresponde à base das imagens. Porém, se houver uma imagem e um texto, o texto pode ultrapassar a linha de base (lembre-se da perna do "p"), portanto uma parte dele estará abaixo do final da imagem.

> Qual a importância prática dele? Imagino que seja importante, já que ele é o valor padrão para `vertical-align`...

O fundamental é entender que o `vertical-align` se refere a como os elementos **dentro de uma mesma caixa de linha** se alinham verticalmente entre si. Por exemplo, o bloco inline abaixo tem 3 caixas de linha próprias, mas está contido numa caixa de linha mais externa. A linha de base dele (a última linha do bloco) determina a linha de base de toda a caixa de linha externa.

```css
p { border: 1px solid red; }
span { 
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem <span>ipsum<br>ipsum<br>ipsum</span> dolor</p>
```