# Padding de baixo maior do que o definido no CSS

Tags: css, padding

Tenho uma situação em que defino o `padding` de uma `div` dentro do `header` com:

```
#header_inn{
   padding: 5px 2%;
   width: 96%;
}
```

Eu quero que os `padding`s `top` e `bottom` tenham exatos `5px`, porém o de baixo fica maior, diferente em relação ao de cima, que está com os `5px`, mas o de baixo ficou com o dobro, `10px` (medido no Photoshop).

Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que o `padding` de baixo fica maior? O que estou fazendo de errado ou deixando de fazer para gerar esse espaço indesejado e impreciso?

Segue o código:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #000;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #fff;
}

header{
   background-color: #51090e;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #7e0e16;
}

footer{
   background: green;
}

#header_inn{
   padding: 5px 2%;
   width: 96%;
}

#header_inn img{
   height: 53px;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div id="header_inn">
      <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
   </div>
</header>
<main>
   main
</main>
<footer>
   footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Acho que era aqui que vc precisava de uma ajuda né. Mas não tem como dar resposta melhor que a do Guilherme. Tem horas que eu mesmo venho consultar aqui uma resposta que eu já dei e não lembro mais como tinha resolvido rss. []´s

Comment: Cara esses dias praticamente não estou entrando a noite, mas durante o dias estou na área, qq coisa é só falar.

Comment: Cara exatamente assim eu nunca fiz, mas com `transition` vc pode brincar um pouco com o http://cubic-bezier.com para ver se vc chega em um resultado que te atende. Se não te atender e vc precisa exatamente de tempo X para ir e tempo 2X para voltar acho que usando dois @kayframes um no :hover e outro quando tirar o :hover pode ser que vc consiga, mas ai tem que testar pq nunca fiz exatamente assim.

Comment: Blz... vou postar uma pergunta então. ObG!

Comment: Engraçado né? Aceitação desfeita depois de meses, sem haver resposta nova alguma, isso porque você diz não levar as coisas para o lado pessoal, ou afirma que não mistura os assuntos, e estranhamente foi depois daquela postagem no Meta. É bom saber, assim não vou mais me prestar a lhe ajudar em nenhuma pergunta sua.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isto ocorre porque a tag `img` por padrão usa `display: inline;`, logo o comportamento não é como de blocos, esse espaçamento seria um espaçamento como ocorre em textos, ou seja o `<img>` acompanha o alinhamento do paragrafo, então este espaçamento abaixo é porque a imagem vai se comportar como se estivesse em cima da linha, se mudar o `vertical-align` inclusive vai notar que ele muda de posição.

Um exemplo mais ou menos para entender o que ocorre, seria isto:

> [image: exemplo com fonte script]

No caso desta fonte usada na imagem, a linha seria o paragrafo, a imagem se alinha bem em cima disto, note que no caso do `G` e `g` eles ficam também em cima, mas com parte que vai abaixo.

Se colocar um `display: block;` (também vai funcionar se usar `float:`) vai notar que isso funciona como quase como deseja:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #000;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #fff;
}

header{
   background-color: #51090e;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #7e0e16;
}

footer{
   background: green;
}

#header_inn{
   padding: 5px 2%;
   width: 96%;
}

#header_inn img{
   height: 53px;
   display: block; /* bloco */
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div id="header_inn">
      <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
   </div>
</header>
<main>
   main
</main>
<footer>
   footer
</footer>
```

---

Outra tentativa de solução seria aplicar `font-size: 0` no elemento pai de onde esta a imagem, assim:

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #000;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #fff;
}

header{
   background-color: #51090e;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #7e0e16;
}

footer{
   background: green;
}

#header_inn{
   padding: 5px 2%;
   width: 96%;
   font-size: 0;
}

#header_inn img{
   height: 53px;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div id="header_inn">
      <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
   </div>
</header>
<main>
   main
</main>
<footer>
   footer
</footer>
```

Comment: @dvd a edição agora na resposta será para usuários que chegarem na sua pergunta e não entenderem bem o comportamento do paragrafo com a imagem, creio que ilustrativo deve ficar mais evidente.

Comment: *esse espaçamento seria um espaçamento como ocorre em textos* – acho que o termo que você está procurando é "altura da linha". É ela que está sendo somada ao padding.

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que é isso mesmo, eu vou revisar em breve para se adequar melhor.

Comment: Lembrei desta minha resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56947