# Espaço indesejado em uma borda com evento hover

Tags: css3, css-hover

Estou tentando replicar o efeito do menu do *OW* de seleção de modos de jogo e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

[image: print do problema - espaço vazio em baixo]

Aparentemente está funcionando direito. Porém, quando a borda aparece, tem um espaçamento extra só embaixo.

Código (replicado do [CodePen](https://codepen.io/utamo/pen/KbOQYM)):

```css
.bastion-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: lightslategray;   
}

.bastion {
    margin: 3px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.bastion-size {
    height: 200px;  
}
.bastion:hover {
    transition: all .5s;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
  <section class="bastion-container">
       <div class="bastion">
           <img class="bastion-size"src="//i.imgur.com/SZ9qGcM.png">
       </div>
       <div class="bastion">
           <img class="bastion-size"src="//i.imgur.com/SZ9qGcM.png">
       </div>
       <div class="bastion">
           <img class="bastion-size"src="//i.imgur.com/SZ9qGcM.png">
       </div>
       
   </section>
```

OBS: Refiz do 0 (https://codepen.io/utamo/pen/EGqExQ) e arrumei, porém não sei onde errei nesse código. Abri no Chrome, chequei `margin` e `padding` e não encontrei nada. É simplesmente um espaço vazio que fica ali...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você resolveria o problema aplicando `display: block` na imagem, ou seja, na classe `.bastion-size`. Isso porque a tag `img` é inline, conforme explicado [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/306276/8063):

**Veja:**

```css
.bastion-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: lightslategray;   
}

.bastion {
    margin: 3px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: all .5s;
  
}
.bastion-size {
    height: 200px;  
    display: block; /* AQUI */
}
.bastion:hover {
    transition: all .5s;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
  <section class="bastion-container">
       <div class="bastion">
           <img class="bastion-size"src="//i.imgur.com/SZ9qGcM.png">
       </div>
       <div class="bastion">
           <img class="bastion-size"src="//i.imgur.com/SZ9qGcM.png">
       </div>
       <div class="bastion">
           <img class="bastion-size"src="//i.imgur.com/SZ9qGcM.png">
       </div>
       
   </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema é porque você colocou o efeito na `div` externa da imagem, assim é aplicada a escala na `div`, mas a imagem não a acompanha, colocando o efeito na própria imagem o problema é solucionado, como no exemplo abaixo:

```css
.bastion-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: lightslategray;   
}

.bastion-size {
    height: 200px;  
}

.bastion {
    margin: 3px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.bastion:hover img {
    transition: all .5s;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
  <section class="bastion-container">
       <div class="bastion">
           <img class="bastion-size"src="//i.imgur.com/SZ9qGcM.png">
       </div>
       <div class="bastion">
           <img class="bastion-size"src="//i.imgur.com/SZ9qGcM.png">
       </div>
       <div class="bastion">
           <img class="bastion-size"src="//i.imgur.com/SZ9qGcM.png">
       </div>
   </section>
```