# Não consigo acessar dados do container

Tags: css

Estou usando `ReactJS` para montar uma página de comidas e estou tendo dificuldades para alterar as propriedades do `Container` por `CSS`.

Aqui um exemplo de como esta no meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde o "1" é controlado pelo `.ImgContainer`:

```
.ImgContainer {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.ImgContainer .Image {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.Body:hover .ImgContainer .Image {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

o "2" pelo `.teste`:

```
.teste{
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #ee1414c5
}
```

e o "3" pelo `.Body`:

```
.Body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #a2de96;
    margin: 8px 32px 8px 0;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

Eu gostaria de retirar essa parte branca do "3" para deixar como na imagem de referencia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não estou conseguindo acessar essa parte do container ou editar. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Estrutura geral do código:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import * as actions from '../../../../../store/actions/actions'

import style from './item.module.css'

function Item(props) {
    const { name, desc, id, imgLink, price } = props
    const item = {
        id: id,
        name: name,
        price: price,
        desc: desc,
        imgLink: imgLink
    }
    return (
        <div className={style.Body}>
            <div className={style.ImgContainer}>
                <div className={style.Image} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imgLink})` }} />
            </div>
            <div className={style.teste} > 
                <span className="font-weight-light pt-2">
                    <p></p>
                    <strong>{name}</strong>
                </span>
                <br />
                <span className={`font-italic font-weight-lighter text-muted ${style.Description}`}>{desc}</span>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className={`mb-2 ${style.Row}`}>
                        <span className={`my-auto font-weight-light ${style.Price}`}>
                            <strong>€</strong> {price}
                        </span>
                        <div className={`my-auto ml-auto ${style.BtnHolder}`}>
                            <button className={style.ItemActionBtn} onClick={() => props.removeItemFromCart(item)}>
                                <i className="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" />
                            </button>
                            <span className={`my-auto mx-1 font-weight-light ${style.Price}`}>
                                <strong> {id in props.itemMap ?
                                    props.cart[props.itemMap[id]].quantity : 0} </strong>
                            </span>
                            <button className={style.ItemActionBtn} onClick={() => props.addItemToCart(item)}>
                                <i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" />
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    cart: state.cart.cart,
    itemMap: state.cart.itemMap
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addItemToCart: item => dispatch(actions.addItemToCart(item)),
    removeItemFromCart: item => dispatch(actions.removeItemFromCart(item)),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Item)
```

Comment: Adicione a estrutura completa do código para que possamos analisar/reproduzir a situação...

Comment: @FelipeDuarte feito!

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt, já tentou remover a propriedade `background-color` do `.Body { ... }` ou mudar assim:  `.Body { background-color: none }` ou criar uma outra classe no seu elemento? `.Body.sem-fundo { background: none }` no seu arquivo: `item.module.css`

Comment: @IvanFerrer sim, a questão é que a foto nao acompanha a parte branca. Mesmo retirando o BACKGROUND-COLOR, o espaço em branco permanece la

Comment: Então, talvez seja porque o seu container é maior de altura, e a imagem menor, e o elemento inferior com os dados Não esteja na altura correta para preencher essa área. O que vc poderia fazer, é ampliar a imagem, usando duas propriedades, `object-fit: cover` e `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Há também a possibilidade de vc subir o elemento 2 para ficar por cima da imagem: `.teste { position: relative; top: -50px;}`, seu container iria se ajustar na altura, no caso, se vc usar um min-height, ao invés de usar um tamanho height fixo.

Comment: @IvanFerrer ele ainda mantem o espaço de baixo :/ https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/LAatdng ja mexi em todas as infos do .Body mas nao consigo setar o tamanho do  container

Comment: Elementos com display igual a inline ou inline-block trabalharão como paragrafos, tendo assim o mesmo comportamento que os textos no mesmo paragrafo terão, o "conceito" é explicado em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56938/o-que-%c3%a9-baseline/56947#56947 e aqui sugiro algumas formas de contornar isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/306277/3635

Comment: Agora é só uma questão da altura do box da imagem...,creio que você precise ajustá-la para se adequar ao tamanho da sua imagem na altura, vc colocou 100%, mas em css, o 100% só é reconhecido dentro de um contexto de altura fixa.

Comment: vc está usando align-items: center; isso faz com que os elementos do seu container fiquem centralizados na altura, mude para: `align-items: flex-start;`